# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm very basic with JavaScript and I'm trying to learn how to save some data into a Server with JavaScript/jQuery and php. 
Here is my code, I'm trying to start to send something via JSON:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Esercizio 1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

  <style>
   .body-cnt {
    width: 80%;
    display: table;
    margin: 20px auto;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="body-cnt">
   <div class="cnt-fields">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="surname">Surname:</label>
     <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <button type="button" id="add-record" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div class="cnt-fields-btns">
     <button type="button" id="new-record" class="btn btn-primary">Add new row</button>
     <button type="button" id="reload-table" class="btn btn-secondary">Load Info</button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <p></p>
   <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>NAME</th>
     <th>SURNAME</th>
     <th>EMAIL</th>
    </thead>
   </table>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var nameValue, surnameValue, emailValue, addBtn;

    addBtn = jQuery('#add-record');

    addBtn.click(function() {
     nameValue = jQuery('#name').value;
     surnameValue =  jQuery('#surname').value;
     emailValue =  jQuery('#email').value;
    });

    // Ajax Request
    jQuery.ajax({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'http://mywebsite/test/controller.php',
     data: {

      test: 'Test'
     },
     success: function(data) {
      var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(parseData);
     }
    })

   });


  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I've got this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

I'm searching everywhere but I really don't understand what it could be. Someone that could give me some hint? :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: The error is coming where you're calling `JSON.parse()`. If the JSON isn't properly formatted, the JSON parse will spit out an error. The fact that it's returning at position 0 tells me that your `controller.php` script probably isn't returning JSON. What I would recommend, in order to debug, would be to put `console.log(data);` above `var parseData...` on a dev/test environment, and figure out what is being returned that JavaScript doesn't like.

Comment: Sounds like you do not have JSON.... `console.log(data)`